# Uniquely identifying actors in scala

Tags: scala, actor, identify

I'm building a simple logging class in scala which would write all log information to a file. This is part of a homework assignment. Hence I cannot use the already available loggers in java or scala or akka libraries. Can any of you please tell how to uniquely identify actors in scala i.e., is there a resource ID or any other ID for each actor. If so, how can it be accessed?

I tried using hashCode() on the actor objects. But it does not give the expected result, as the value changes for each object and many objects can be created for a single actor.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value changes for each object and many objects can be created for a single actor"?

Comment: @sourcedelica hashCode() for any object returns a unique value in Java. This value can be used for uniquely identifying that object. However for a single actor class, we would be creating multiple instances in the program. when we use hashCode() on these instances, we will be getting unique values each instance. Hence I couldn't use this method for identifying each actor uniquely.

Comment: Ok - so you mean identifying the type of actor, not the actor itself.  Because the hashcode will identify the actor (at least in Akka).  Are you using Akka?

Comment: @sourcedelica No. This is a homework assignment and I was asked to use only scala or java libraries.

Comment: So you are trying to identify the type of actor not the actor itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using akka actors you can get the name of the actor by looking at self.path (self is an ActorRef)

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.4/#akka.actor.ActorPath

EDIT:

If you are using scala actors then you could do something like...

```
class MyActor(name: String) extends Actor { 
  def act() {
    receive {
      case _ => println("Message on actor: " + name)
    }
  } 
}
val actor1 = new MyActor("actor1")
val actor2 = new MyActor("actor2")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want. However I should not use akka libraries for this homework assignment. Do you know any scala solution for the same?

Comment: Why can't you use akka? Did they specifically say you cant use libraries?. Anyway provided another solution for you.